# Android N: Platform Migration toward OpenJDK 8

Tags: java, android, android-n-preview

I am reading about [Android N preview](http://developer.android.com/preview/behavior-changes.html#open-jdk), and one thing caught my eye especially.

> Platform Migration toward OpenJDK 8

I didn't saw it clearly in the article so I want to ask you:

### Does Android N brings native support to jdk 8?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes Android N is going to get native support to jdk8 .But as of now only a few language features are supported.for more refer 
[Java 8 Language Features](https://developer.android.com/preview/j8-jack.html) .